# Can't move icons on desktop

Tags: desktop, icons, windows-8.1, fences

I found that I can't move icons across Desktop.

When I start dragging of an icon, refuse cursor appears (black ring with single black diagonal strike) and nothing happens. Position of an icon does not change.

View -> Auto Arrange is OFF.

Veiw -> Align Icons to Grid is OFF.

Fences 2.01 is installed.

Windows 8.1 Professional is running.

Comment: Did you hit the escape a few times to if it helps (like [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/cant-move-shortcut-icons-on-my-desktop-to/7200ee9c-1b39-4d71-8c27-14350c75b5bd)).

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before. Its an issue with fences.

You can verify this by removing fences.

The newer version of fences, 2.11.610 has this fixed.

Upgrade and you will note that it'll work.